# Error : pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'backports.functools-lru-cache' distribution was not found and is required by pylint

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-analysis, pylint

I am trying to run Pylint and I am getting the below error:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'backports.functools-lru-cache' distribution was not found and is required by pylint

I found the below link, but not sure what to do with these files or where to place them.
https://pypi.python.org/simple/backports.functools-lru-cache/

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of pylint is it ?

Comment: How did you install pylint?

Comment: i used pip install pylint command

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I installed two missing dependencies (wrong configuration on the pylint or not updated pip??)
Just do:

```
pip install backports.functools_lru_cache
```

then if you get an error like:

```
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
```

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: configparser

just do:

```
pip install configparser
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell certain versions of RHEL/CentOS have some sort of problem with the backports.ssl-match-hostname package in their yum repositories which can lead to problems when other backports packages get updated from PyPI. Specifically, in a RHEL7.2 environment I've reproduced the problem as follows:

```
> yum install python-pip  # indirectly installs backports.ssl-match-hostname
> pip2 install pylint     # indirectly installs backports.functools_lru_cache
> pip2 install --upgrade backports.ssl-match-hostname  # install latest package from pypi, which effectively corrupts backports.functools_lru_cache
> python2 -m pylint --version   # fails with missing import backports.functools_lru_cache
```

The only way to avoid this that I've found is to replace the yum-installed package with the equivalent one from PyPI. This can be done as follows:

```
> yum install python-pip  # installs backports.ssl-match-hostname as a transitive dependency
> pip2 freeze > temp_reqs.txt  # take a snapshot of the installed packages and versions
> pip2 uninstall backports.ssl-match-hostname  # remove the yum installed package
> pip2 install -r temp_reqs.txt  # reinstall the same version of the backports package, but install from PyPI
```

Now the installed packages should work as expected. Performing the following test case confirms this:

```
> pip2 install pylint
> pip2 install --upgrade backports.ssl-match-hostname  # previously caused corruption of backports.functools_lru_cache used by pylint
> python2 -m pylint --version  # now works correctly
```

Hopefully this helps others with this problem.

Comment: I'm running in to this under OSX too, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when running within a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) on CentOS 7.

On CentOS, the backports module is packaged as a yum package (`python-backports.x86_64`).

The solution was to create the virtualenv using the [`--system-site-packages`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option) option.

First verify that the ``python-backports` package is installed:

`yum list installed | grep python-backports`

Then create/recreate your virtual environment:

`virtualenv env --system-site-packages`

This allows the virtualenv's pylint to see the backports module when installing.

Then install pylint within the virtual environment:

`env/bin/pip install pylint`